# How can I create a VBA code to print our multiple copies of the same sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button in excel and I want it to print an X amount of copies. Like Say 10 so items come into stock. I want to print 10 copies. I have formula that looks up the item info. I just want a code that Prints so many times for the "quantity" that I will fill in.

Comment: You want to print the sheet??? Or do you want to select a range in the sheet and print only the range?

Comment: I want to print Multiple copies of that one sheet. Like right now I have Sheets("name").PrintOut but i want to be able to print a number a copies from a web developer box.

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=Range("A1").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially..

```
Sub PrintXCopies()
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut , , Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

where the number of copies to print is in cell A1. You should add error-handling in case this is not a number, or a sensible number. Something like:

```
Sub PrintXCopies()
    If IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value) Then
        If Range("A1").Value >= 1 And Range("A1").Value < 10 Then
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut , , Range("A1").Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```